# How to plot a Gantt chart

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, plotly, gantt-chart

This topic was addressed in other questions but none of the recommendations worked in my case.

I have macOS M1

```
#Manage the data 
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#Graphic tools
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import plotly.figure_factory as ff
from plotly.figure_factory import create_gantt
from datetime import date

# Make data for chart
df = [dict(Task="Job A", Start='2009-01-01',
       Finish='2009-02-30', Complete=10),
      dict(Task="Job B", Start='2009-03-05',
       Finish='2009-04-15', Complete=60),
      dict(Task="Job C", Start='2009-02-20',
       Finish='2009-05-30', Complete=95)]

# Create a figure with Plotly colorscale
fig = create_gantt(df, colors='Blues', index_col='Complete',
               show_colorbar=True, bar_width=0.5,
               showgrid_x=True, showgrid_y=True)
fig.show()
```

After running the code (Jupiter notebook), there are no errors. However, it is just a blank output cell. Nothing to see.

I checked ALL previous answers. Unfortunately nothing works so far.

the use of jupyter labextension install jupyterlab-plotly does not work because lab extension is deprecated according to my output.

Totally confused. matplotlib works fine with other programs on the same notebook.

UPDATE:

I tried this and it worked:

```
import plotly.express as px
fig = px.bar(x=["a", "b", "c"], y=[1, 3, 2])

import plotly.graph_objects as go
fig_widget = go.FigureWidget(fig)
fig_widget
```

So there is a situation that just plotly does not work in MY system (while it does in other configs - see Trenton's response) BUT with it works with graph_objects.

What do you suggest?

UPDATE

it worked after I added two last lines of code.  Still it must have worked with show()

```
# Make data for chart
import plotly.express as px
df = [dict(Task="Job A", Start='2009-01-01',
       Finish='2009-02-30', Complete=10),
  dict(Task="Job B", Start='2009-03-05',
       Finish='2009-04-15', Complete=60),
  dict(Task="Job C", Start='2009-02-20',
       Finish='2009-05-30', Complete=95)]

# Create a figure with Plotly colorscale
fig2 = create_gantt(df, colors='Blues', index_col='Complete',
               show_colorbar=True, bar_width=0.5,
               showgrid_x=True, showgrid_y=True)
#fig2.show()

fig_widget2 = go.FigureWidget(fig2)
fig_widget2
```

Comment: This is not reproducible. See [code and plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZGbo.png) in Jupyter. Also, this is a plotly-python question, not a matplotlib question.

Comment: You will **probably** need the jupyter - jupyterlab plotly extenstion

Comment: Use plotly express timeline